# How to work with Web apps in Android and phone gap

Tags: android, cordova

Hi All I am an absolute beginner in android, and i need to create web app using phone gap. I saw the documentation for web apps in developer guide, and want to create a web app. My question is, i don't know how to start, what are the tools needed and how to develop, please help. your precious advice is much needed for me. Please show me the way how to develop web apps for android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- download phonegap from [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/archive/2.9.1.zip)
- Create an android project with [eclipse](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html)
- import cordoba library to the lib folder of your project (you can find it on the android folder of the phonegap zip you downloaded)
- replace the code of your MainActivity.java with this:

```
package com.example.MyFirstApp;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

- Create the directory in your android project: assets/www/
- There you put your index.html file and ready to go, you can put also your web stuff like css and js in the www directory